# How to deliver to multiple destinations (email addresses and (via dovecot-lda) mailboxes)

Tags: exim, dovecot

I'm using exim and dovecot. All users are virtual, i.e. they come from a database. A lookup for the destination addresses for a given `localpart@domain` may yield multiple rows containing either the target mailbox or the target email address.

The following router works fine for delivering all emails properly:

```
pg_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  directory_transport = address_file
  data = ${sg{\
              ${lookup pgsql { SELECT CASE WHEN substr(c_dest, 1, 1) = '/' THEN (c_dest||'@@'||c_domain) ELSE c_dest END FROM aliases WHERE c_local = '${quote_pgsql:$local_part}' AND c_domain = realDomain('${quote_pgsql:$domain}');}}}\
              {/(.+)@@(.+)}\
              {/var/spool/mail/\$2/\$1/Maildir/}}
```

That "code" is old and initially not written by me, but it works and I see why: If the destination is a mailbox (`/mailboxname`) it converts it to a path which will cause the `directory_transport` to be invoked. Otherwise the destination is an address which will cause the *redirect* driver to deal with it.

However, I'd like to use use `dovecot-lda` for local delivery now.

This means I'll need to call a transport which will then take the mailboxname and domain from `$address_data` and deliver to it:

```
dovecot_lda:
  driver = pipe
  command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d ${extract{dest}{$address_data}}@${extract{domain}{$address_data}} -f $sender_address -a $original_local_part@$original_domain
  ...
```

However, I don't see a way to make the `redirect` router call that transport. When using a separate `accept` router in addition to the `redirect` router it will only deliver to the first destination mailbox since it doesn't seem to handle multi-row results in the `address_data` lookup of the router:

```
pg_dovecot:
  driver = accept
  transport = dovecot_lda
  condition    = ${lookup pgsql { SELECT substr(c_dest, 2) AS dest, c_domain AS domain FROM aliases WHERE c_local = '${quote_pgsql:$local_part}' AND c_domain = realDomain('${quote_pgsql:$domain}') AND substr(c_dest, 1, 1) = '/'; }}
  address_data = ${lookup pgsql { SELECT substr(c_dest, 2) AS dest, c_domain AS domain FROM aliases WHERE c_local = '${quote_pgsql:$local_part}' AND c_domain = realDomain('${quote_pgsql:$domain}') AND substr(c_dest, 1, 1) = '/'; }}
```

I wonder if there's a way to solve this problem.